# Entity relationship where one entity has references to 2 of the same entity type?

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee, database-design

I'm working on a project for university that requires me to implement a basic Paypal-like money transfer system. I'm currently modelling the relationships between entities. My current problem involves 2 entities: User and Transaction.

The logic is that a Transaction has a sender User and a recipient User, and the amount of money sent. I'm struggling with modelling this relationship however as I can't figure out the correct way of forming the relationship between User and Transaction.

Is it correct to have 2 seperate one-to-one relationships on the Transaction entity which references the same attribute on the User but with a different column name on the database table?

Comment: do you mean sql model or java object model

Comment: it's not Java , it's modeling a database design !

Comment: Model this situation with two relationships, not one...

Comment: I'm working with Java but I'm struggling more in a conceptual way not syntax.

Comment: In your situation there are two different relationships, at the conceptual level, between Users and Transactions. And there is nothing wrong about it...

Comment: @Renzo That's what I was thinking, does it make sense to use 2 seperate   one-to-one relationships or 2 seperate many-to-one relationships?

Comment: Since a User can be the sender of money (as well as the recipient) in many Transactions, the relationships are both one-to-many.

Comment: That makes sense thanks. If you post your comment as an answer i can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classical situation: two Entities are connected by two different relationships. In this case you have a one-to-may relationship Send between User and Transaction, and a one-to-many relationship Receive between User and Transaction.

And you should treat them as any other relationship for what concerns the implementation. For instance, in a relational database you can have a table `Users` with its attributes, and a table `Transactions` with, in addition to the amount of money and other relevant information, two different attributes,  `sender` and `receiver`, both of which foreign keys for the table User.